# Link to pricing for Stack Overflow job listings is broken on the German site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the German version of the Stack Overflow job listings page is a link to the pricing for job listings. This link is broken, probably because prices aren't listed anymore in the English version, and nobody updated the German version of the page.

The link is on [this page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent/plattform/sourcing/stellenanzeigen) as "*zu unseren Preisen*". It leads to [the following page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent/plattform/sourcing/preise), which gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this. It was missed in the content management system during our testing and is now resolved.

Comment: while you're at it, the last button on the page "jetzt Rückruf anfordern" doesn't have the hover effect like the other ones. I suspect that isn't intentional

Comment: This has also been fixed now. Thanks!